# Centralizing or consolidating LINQ select

Tags: c#, linq

How do I refactor this code so I can centralize the projection?

```
public IEnumerable<ItemDto> GetItemsByType(int itemId, ItemType itemType)
{
    IEnumerable<ItemDto> items = null;
    try
    {
        var tempItems= _Items.Get(i => i.ItemId == itemId
            && o.Active == true);
        switch (itemType)
        {
            case ItemType.Normal:
                items = from item in tempItems
                        select new ItemDto
                        {
                            // many fields here
                        };
                break;
            case ItemType.Damaged:
                items = from item in tempItems
                        join itemDetail in _ItemDetails.Get() on item.ID equals itemDetail.ItemID
                        select new ItemDto
                        {
                            // many fields here
                        };
                break;
            case ItemType.Fixed:
                items = from item in tempItems
                        join itemDetail in _ItemDetails.Get() on item.ID equals itemDetail.ItemID
                        where item.Status.ToLower() == "fixed"
                        select new ItemDto
                        {
                            // many fields here
                        };
                break;

            // more case statements here...

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    catch { ... }
}
```

Basically, I have lots of case statements and a long projection on each case statement. I'm worried that once the DTO needs to change, say add a new field, the other cases' projection might not be consistent with each other (forgot or missed updating). How can I centralize this?

Comment: Are each of the `// many fields here` the same code?

Comment: Yes, they are the same code

Comment: Then my answer may be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you approach it like this?

```
var query = tempItems.AsQueryable();

switch(itemType)
{
   case ItemType.Damaged:
        query.Join(...);
        break;

   case ItemType.Fixed:
        query.Where(...);
}

query.Select(e => new ItemDto{//Lots of properties});

return query.ToList();
```

Comment: The other answers were also helpful but this ultimately lead me to my solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
var baseQuery = from item in tempItems select item;
switch (itemType)
{
     case ItemType.Fixed:
         baseQuery = from item in baseQuery where item.ID equals itemID select item;
         break;
}

return (from item in baseQuery select new ItemDTO (...projection here... ));
```

Comment: The thing here is some of the select cases have joins to other collection whose fields I need for the DTO. If I do 'select item' only, those fields from the joined collections wouldn't be available to me.

Answer (score 1):

Would this kind of approach help?

```
public IEnumerable<ItemDto> GetItemsByType2(int itemId, ItemType itemType)
{
    var cases = new Dictionary<ItemType, Func<IEnumerable<ItemDto>, IEnumerable<ItemDto>>>()
    {
        { ItemType.Normal, xs => xs },
        { ItemType.Damaged, xs =>
            from item in xs
            join itemDetail in _ItemDetails.Get() on item.ID equals itemDetail.ItemID
            select item },
        { ItemType.Fixed, xs =>
            from item in xs
            join itemDetail in _ItemDetails.Get() on item.ID equals itemDetail.ItemID
            where item.Status.ToLower() == "fixed"
            select item },
    };

    return cases[itemType](_Items.Get(i => i.ItemId == itemId && o.Active == true))
        .Select(x => new ItemDto { .... });
}
```